# Prevent Ajax Form Submission Without Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, ajaxform

I'm trying to get some client side validation working to prevent a form submission occurring if an object has no value.  I've been plugging away at this for a while now but cannot get a satisfactory solution.

My form submission Js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#localUsersDateTime').val(setLocalDateTime());

    $('#createentry').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: checkTextObjHasValue($('#newentry'), 'You need to add some text.'),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#entries-list').prepend('<li>' + $('#newentry').val() + '</li>');
            $('#newentry').val('').blur();
        },
        error: function (xhr)
        {
            try {
                var json = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
                alert(json.errorMessage);
            } catch (e) {
                alert('Oops, Something very bad has happened');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

However when the page loads it runs my checkTextObjHasValue() specified in the beforeSubmit: function so that check needs to only execute on actual form submission.

```
function checkTextObjHasValue(obj, message) {

    if ($(obj).val() === '') {
        alert(message);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

How can I prevent this beforeSubmit: callback from being executed when just loading the page and only execute on actual form submission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `beforeSubmit` option expects a reference to a function. You were immediately calling a function. Try using this:

```
beforeSubmit: function () {
    return checkTextObjHasValue($('#newentry'), 'You need to add some text.');
},
```

The added `return` allows for the submission to cancel if `false` is actually returned (which is possible in `checkTextObjHasValue` under a certain condition).

Technically, it *could've* worked if you returned a function from `checkTextObjHasValue`, but I think this way is a little cleaner. And it lets you customize it in case you want to validate several fields.

**UPDATE:**

Like in the documentation for the plugin, you could take this approach:

```
beforeSubmit: beforeSubmitHandler,
```

And then define a function separately like this:

```
function beforeSubmitHandler() {
    return checkTextObjHasValue($('#newentry'), 'You need to add some text.');
}
```

Comment: @hop Why do you say that? The example shows a function reference. If there was a function being called (like in the OP), then I'd understand confusion. Also, http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object says "callback function" for `beforeSubmit`. Functions don't magically return functions when you call them. And I'm not sure of your point - if the documentation is misleading in whatever way, that's not my fault

Comment: I never meant its your fault at all. Just wanted to learn and I am confused. From what you explained, I will have a second look at the documentation.

Comment: That is an oversight on my part, I'm still learning a lot about JavaScript in general, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @hop Ahh okay, it just **seemed** like you thought it was my fault the documentation was misleading (althought I didn't think you meant that). You're right though, the documentation doesn't give many examples. The way they set up the examples is an option, among several. The point to remember is that it expects a function reference - and that can be achieved in several ways.

Comment: @Jammer No problem! This is a common problem, because people think calling a function is the same thing as a function reference. And hop pointed out the documentation isn't the best.

Comment: This is now working in that the submission is prevented if the textarea object is empty but the alert box with the message is never shown.